# Why does my Tic Tac Toe logic have errors sometimes?

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

Im new to posting questions here so let me know if ive done something wrong. So this program works fine 90% of the time as seen here.[image]

But then the logic is off sometimes as seen here.
Ive looked through my code for a while so ive finally given in and ask for help! My logic() function seems to be accurate. Ive matched all possible routes to win; rows, columns and diagonals. For some reason if the top row is -> 'X' | 'O' | 'X' -> it declares player one (x) to be the winner. Any ideas?

[image]

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void drawBoard();
char board[3][3] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};   // 3x3 board
char player = 'X';
void game();
void toggle();
char logic();
void winner();
int main()
{
    drawBoard();
    while(1){
        game();
        drawBoard();
        toggle();
        if(logic() == 'X')
            cout << "Player 1 (X) Wins!" << endl;
        else if(logic() == 'O')
            cout << "Player 2 (O) Wins!" << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}

void drawBoard(){

    system("cls");
    cout << setw(35) << "Tic Tac Toe V 2.0! " << endl << endl;
    cout << setw(21) << board[0][0] << " | " << board[0][1] << " | " << board[0][2] << endl;
    cout << setw(30) << " --------- " << endl;
    cout << setw(21) << board[1][0] << " | " << board[1][1] << " | " << board[1][2] << endl;
    cout << setw(30) << " --------- " << endl;
    cout << setw(21) << board[2][0] << " | " << board[2][1] << " | " << board[2][2] << endl;

}

void game(){

    int input;

    cout << "Make your move..." << endl;
    cin >> input;

    if(input == 1)
        board[0][0] = player;
    else if(input == 2)
        board[0][1] = player;
    else if(input == 3)
        board[0][2] = player;
    else if(input == 4)
        board[1][0] = player;
    else if(input == 5)
        board[1][1] = player;
    else if(input == 6)
        board[1][2] = player;
    else if(input == 7)
        board[2][0] = player;
    else if(input == 8)
        board[2][1] = player;
    else if(input == 9)
        board[2][2] = player;


}

void toggle(){

    if(player == 'X')
        player = 'O';
    else
        player = 'X';

}


char logic(){
// Player 1
    /// Across
    if(board[0][0] == 'X' && board[0][1] == 'X' && board[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    else if(board[1][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    else if(board[2][0] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    /// Columns
    else if(board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][0] == 'X' && board[2][0] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    else if(board[0][1] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    else if(board[0][2] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    /// Diagonals
    else if(board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    else if(board[0][2] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][0] == 'X')
        return 'X';

// Player 2
    /// Across
    if(board[0][0] == 'O' && board[0][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    else if(board[1][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    else if(board[2][0] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    /// Columns
    else if(board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][0] == 'O' && board[2][0] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    else if(board[0][1] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    else if(board[0][2] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    /// Diagonals
    else if(board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    else if(board[0][2] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][0] == 'O')
        return 'O';
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Since the problem seems to be in the win detection, that would be a good place to start looking. Increasing the warning level when you compile would also help.

Comment: logic fails to return a value if no one won. That is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function `logic()`, you are missing a return statement, meaning that if none of the conditions are satisficed, the function will just return anything that could have been in that register. I found that if you add a `return 0;` to the end of the function, you don't get that behavior.